# How to get app to run at iPhone size on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode

I have submitted an app to the app store twice now. It has been rejected both times returning with a message saying : "We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.1" 
How do I make the app run at iPhone resolution on iPad?

Comment: Does your app even support iPad? It sounds like most of your development focus was iPhone.

Comment: Does your iPhone-only app run on 3.5" iPhones? Make it do that and it should work on iPads. You can test using the simulator.

Comment: My app does not support ipad but I cannot find a way to submit it only for iphone